# Cocoa Touch: Capturing Still Poster Frame from Video File?

Tags: iphone, ios4, video, quicktime, mpeg-4

I have an app that records videos. It will display each video in its interface, and I'd like to have a little thumbnail to represent each video. OS X shows a preview of the video, a poster frame taken some few seconds into the file. I'd like to do something similar. I've heard it called a "poster frame" but the Googles aren't helping for this one.

Can anyone point me at the appropriate API that would help me do this?

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you’re looking for is the [AVAssetImageGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009514) class. Create an AVAsset from your video file (using its `+assetWithURL:` method—note that for URLs from the filesystem you **must** either prepend `file://` to the path or use NSURL’s `+fileURLWithPath:`), set up a generator with that asset once it’s done loading, and use the generator’s `-copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error:` or `-generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:completionHandler:` to get the thumbnails.

Comment: your post doesn't answer the question. The question is how to extract the poster frame of a video. Using AVAssetImageGenerator you can extract any frame of a video but you did not explain how to extract the poster frame that may not be the first frame, for example.

Comment: The “poster frame” as defined in the question is a frame “taken some few seconds into the file”, which is trivial to acquire with either of the APIs suggested. Is there another definition you think is missing here?

Comment: Duck is right. Movie authors can define a particular frame as a poster frame using ffmpeg (and other tools). That frame can be any frame in the movie and is chosen by the author. That is the frame that is usually defined as the "poster frame". Otherwise it's just some random frame, and possibly unrepresentative of the video as a whole.